# Unity 2D controller coding issues

Tags: unityscript

I am kind of new to Unity and I am trying to make a game using various tutorials for character controlling but recently I ran into a tutorial where they used this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class controller : MonoBehaviour {
public float maxspeed = 10f;
bool facingRight = true;
void Start ()
{}
void FixedUpdate ()
{
float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
if (move > 0 &&!facingRight)
Flip ();
else if (move <0 && facingRight)
Flip ();
}
void Flip()
{
facingRight = !facingRight;
Vector3 theScale = tranform.localScale;
theScale.x *= -1;
transform.localScale = theScale;
}
}
```

Thing is that it does not work when I type it into my MonoDevelop Unity Javascript. So I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, I am getting multiple errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes are meant to be in c# I think. Try typing them in C#.